# Open detailview of contact of address book and filled detail and save it

Tags: iphone

I want to open detail view of contact and then. i want to save in adress book. please give me a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint 1: Address Book Programming Guide for iPhone OS.

Hint 2: ABPersonViewController.

That is all you need to read and save data from the Apple address book, and present a reasonable UI to display the data.  See the QuickContacts sample if you need code examples.

Comment: Quick contacts is a very nice example. I refered it. I can store contact. and then i display that contact in edit mode. but i want open new contact page with filled detail before saved. Thanks for help. Please help me

Comment: Thank you very much. i am able to set all details of contact. and it works fine